# manage the latest data received from a serial port

Tags: .net, vb.net, split, richtextbox

I have a problem with this RichTextBox.

I have a GPS module that sends data *every second.* My aim is to get only a line every minute. A timer tick process is something in my mind.

---

**Problem 1**
`rtb` doesn't display the *latest* line of string in the process.
Initially, it can display like 3 lines, but that's it, the next bursts of strings will appear *out of sight,* meaning it receives the data, but on the bottom and every time I scroll down, it directs me at the top 3 lines. Though not really a concern since I just need the data, I want to see it as I work so I will feel comfortable.

---

**Problem 2**
*sample data*

[image]

I only need the line of `$GPRMC`. I can just locate a line with that specific text right? the problem is that every second it gives me that line `ID` so its not unique. A suggestion from you guys will definitely help.

---

**GOAL**

- display the latest data given by the module from the richtextbox
- be able to parse the latest `$GPRMC` line every minute, something like:

  ```
  For each word in GPRMCLine
      array = word.Split(","c)
      'save to database
  Next
  ```

**UPDATE:** is it possible to locate `$GPRMC` line from the module(variable) directly rather putting it first on a richtextbox?

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of stuff out there for processing NEMA sequences. Any chance you can use an existing library or code base?

Take a look at this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23135/Mapping-with-a-GPS-and-C